# How can I load SunCalc without using RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have this example code that uses RequireJS:

```
require(['jquery', 'SunCalc'], function ($, SunCalc) {
    var position = SunCalc.getMoonPosition(new Date(), 51.5, -0.1);
});
```

I don't want to use RequireJS but I want to use the SunCalc library. I've installed it via npm and created a gulp task to minify the library file and include it but how could I do the above without RequireJS?

Comment: Why no Node with NPM?

Comment: The bulk of my code is written in jQuery so don't want to jump to requirejs just to include one library.

Comment: It depends on how that library source is loaded; Typically they use commonjs form so you'd go something like:
var SunCalc = require('suncalc');
actually I copied taht from their github. So that should work.

Comment: Ok, but you have Node.js right? Assuming that you're using NPM?

Comment: @PaulJeromeBordallo Thanks but is there anyway to avoid using require? Why can I not use it like any other JS plugin? Load the library then use?

Comment: I put my answer below-- the source shows it loads as a global if you are not using any module/dependency loader like requireJS. On the other hand, if your script loads one, then do:
var SunCalc = require('suncalc')
require() is not necessarily requireJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their github source, it loads as a global, if you are not using a dependency loader like requireJS.
So, SunCalc.getMoonPosition() should work after you've included the source. Much the same as jquery loading as a global.